# How to add background color to this javascript elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a javascript code and I would like to see physically this boxes:

```
var dest0   = [
        { id:'target00',  dstX:58, dstY:357, rectX:60, rectY:357, rectW:155, rectH:50},
        { id:'target01',  dstX:210, dstY:357, rectX:212, rectY:357, rectW:155, rectH:50},
        { id:'target02',  dstX:375, dstY:357, rectX:372, rectY:357, rectW:155, rectH:50},
        { id:'target03',  dstX:554, dstY:357, rectX:538, rectY:357, rectW:155, rectH:50},
        { id:'target04',  dstX:713, dstY:357, rectX:713, rectY:357, rectW:155, rectH:50},
        { id:'target05',  dstX:865, dstY:357, rectX:887, rectY:357, rectW:155, rectH:50}
      ];
```

there's a way to include for example a background-color: red; to it to see them on the index.html file? thanks!

Comment: What have you tried please?

Comment: Mode details needed. How are you converting this structure to HTML? Are they used as SVG? What have you tried and where are you having an issue?

Answer (score 0):

Since dest0 is a JSON object, the code sample you provided won't render anything. My advice would be to look at the rendering code and see what kinds of properties you can pass in to set the background color, or if you can manually specify CSS styles for each rectangle. If you have access to API documentation, that would go a long way!